# display query result into send mail controller

Tags: codeigniter

I want to display my query result into my sendmail controller like this :

Controller

```
function contact()
{
    $data['email'] = $this->Pgallery_model->get_Email();
            $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';

            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->to(/*here query result*/);

            $this->email->send();               
            $this->load->view('contact_success', $data);
    }
```

Model

```
function get_Email()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('select email from setup');
    return $query->result();
}
```

how to get query into my delivery mail?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

To get the query result you should use:

```
$result  = $this->db->result();
```

This will get you an *object* you will then have to do something like this:

```
echo $result->email;
```

I would like to point out to you that using camelcase AND underscore is mostly bad practice.

```
get_Email() should either be getEmail() or get_email()
```

Comment: could you tell me more specifically? because I had try with your suggestion and its not change at all. I just want that email to  `$this->email->to(/*here query result*/);` is dynamic and I can change with another email. Thank you

Comment: what is your result right now, and what do you expect? I have edited my answer